# перемножить нужные индексы из двух разных списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!

Задание такое:

```
Sample Input:

a3b4c2e10b1

Sample Output:

aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeb
```

Мое решение:

```py
user_print = list(map(str, input().split()))
#numb_list = user_print.split()
print(user_print)
alph_list = []
num_list = []
for i in user_print[0]:
    if i.isalpha():
        alph_list.append(i)
    
    elif i.isdigit():
        num_list.append(i)
        num_list = list(map(int, num_list))
        

for a in alph_list:
    for j in num_list:
        result = a * j
        print(result, end="")
```

Получается 'aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccceeeeeeeeeeebbbbbbbbbbb' вместо 'aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeb'.

Проблема в том, что не получается умножить букву только на следующее после нее число, она умножается на все числа. Как тут быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похожая тема уже была ранее на форуме, но найти что-то не смог. Удобно для подобной замены пользоваться функцией замены в регулярных выражениях. Используете шаблон поиска, для которого добавляете функцию замены, которая преобразует найденный фрагмент.

```
import re

strng = 'a1b2c3g10'

out = re.sub('(\w)(\d+)', lambda x: x[1]*int(x[2]), strng)
```

Вывод

```
abbcccgggggggggg
```

Comment: крутое решение!

Answer (score 3):

Первое, надо отделить числа, а не цифры.

Делаем так:

1. Пробегаемся по всей строке
2. Все буквы собираем в список (упорядоченно)
3. Инициализирую пустую строку, куда будем складывать цифры и пробелы в случае, если попадается буква
4. На выходе будем иметь две переменные: один со списком (буквы) и один со строкой (числа разделенные пробелом)

```py
a = "a3b4c2e10b1"
alph_list = []
num_string = ""
for i in a:
    if i.isalpha():
        alph_list.append(i)
        num_string += " "
    else:
        num_string += i    
    

print(num_string)
print(alph_list)

# OUT
#  3 4 2 10 1
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'b']
```

Теперь можно сделать из строки с числами список и получать результат умножением каждой буквы на соответствующее число

```py
num_list = num_string.split()
result = []
for n in range(len(alph_list)):
    result.append(alph_list[n] * int(num_list[n]))


print(result)
print("".join(result))

# OUT
# ['aaa', 'bbbb', 'cc', 'eeeeeeeeee', 'b']
# aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeb
```

Answer (score 2):

Такой же алгоритм решения как и у [Дмитрия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209304/dmitry), единственное отличие что я использовал регулярные выражения.

```py
import re


def multipleOutput(a):
    nums = re.findall(r'\d+', a)
    for num in nums:
        a = a.replace(num, "")

    a = list(a)
    if len(a) != len(nums):
        print("Error")
        return

    output = ""
    for idx, char in enumerate(a):
        output += char * int(nums[idx])

    print(output)


s = input()
multipleOutput(s)
```